# desktop computer with 2 ethernet ports and 6 or 8 cores

Tags: motherboard

I am trying to find a reliable motherboard with 2 ethernet ports that can each handle at least a 1 Gbit/s, that supports a 6 or 8 core CPU (I was looking at [these](https://ark.intel.com/products/family/79318/Intel-High-End-Desktop-Processors) cpu-s). I found it extremely hard to search for motherboards with 2 ethernet ports as this is seemingly not an issue for most people.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: If you are able to settle with a PCIe card, I suggest looking at a Dual 10Gbps NIC instead.

Comment: [Newegg lists about 20 of them](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&Subcategory=280&N=100007627%20600533617%20600026698%208000%204814%20600533616%20601205171&IsNodeId=1&IsPowerSearch=1), ranging in price from $180 to $650, with a corresponding range of capabilities.  Do you have any criteria beyond "dual LAN" and "Intel High-End processor"?